# How to get sublime text 3 editor to auto-complete the "{% " with " %}" to save time?

Tags: django, sublimetext3, jinja2

I have started developing django apps with Sublime Text 3, and find the "{% %}" brackets in jinja logic to be very tedious to type, so i wonder is there a way to auto-complete the "{% " bracket with " %}"  to save some time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try creating a snippet for speeding things up.

Click Tools -> Developer -> New Snippet

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
{% ${1:} %}
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>insert-a-trigger-to-activate-on-tab</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <!-- <scope>source.python</scope> -->
</snippet>
```

or, someone else has made a bunch of these here:
https://github.com/squ1b3r/Djaneiro